# getting nil value while parsing JSON in swift using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift

i am parsing "switch_name" from switch array but i am getting nil value while parsing

```
{
"status": "true",
"result": {
    "hubs": [
        {
            "hub_id": "1",
            "user_id": "35",
            "switch": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "hub_id": "1",
                    "switch_name": "Test2",
                    "user_id": "35",
                    "serial_no": "445112",
                    "topic_sense": "rer",
                    "device_room": "25",
                    "switch_type": "LIGHTS",
                    "types_of_relay_switch": "S"
                }
            ],
            "relay": []
        }
    ],
    "switchwithouhub": []
}
```

}

how i am parsing : -

```
let sName = jsonDict.value(forKeyPath: "result.hubs.switch.switch_name") as? [String]
```

i am getting nil value while parsing switch_name.
please help and suggest how can i parse JSON

Comment: `result.hubs` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: I don't know more about keyPath use but **hubs** is array don't you need to define index or any thing ?

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

See you Json in proper format check which data type is and define Array or dictionary or a single object is there.
You will definitely find something wrong

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access the element of an arrays (hubs, switch) directly. You must provide the proper index to access the item.

`let sName = jsonDict.value(forKeyPath: "result.hubs[0].switch[0].switch_name") as? String`

**UPDATE:** You can use SwiftyJson for parsing json data.

```
import SwiftyJSON

do { let jsonData = try JSON(data: response.data) {
  let names = jsonData["hubs"][0]["switch"].array.flatMap({ (switch) -> String in 

  return switch.name
})
}
catch {
  print("Swifty Error")
}
```

Comment: This still isn't quite right. The final result is a `String`, not `[String]`.

Comment: but , if there is multiple objects in the switch array then how we can parse switch_name in array

Comment: You can use Map or Flatmap which will return the array of names.

`let names = result.hubs[0].switch.flatMap({ (item) -> String in
    return item.name
})`

Comment: I have updated my answer, you may need to tweak some logic, I have tried to show the way you have to parse json object.